# how to filter entity type framework object by its child object value properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity framework object called batch, this object has a 1 to many relationship to items.

so 1 batch has many items. and each item has many issues.

I want to filter the for batch items that have a certain issue code (x.code == issueNo).
I have written the following but Im getting this error:

```
        items = batch.Select(b => b.Items
                     .Where(i => i.ItemOrganisations
                     .Select(o => o
                     .Issues.Select(x => x.Code == issueNo))));
```

Error 1:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>>' to 'bool'
```

Error 2:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Ebiquity.Reputation.Neptune.Model.Item,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Comment: I've not a compiler right here now, but maybe something like this could work: items = batch.items.Select(x=> x.Issues.Any(i=>i.Code == issueNo));

Comment: You probably don't want to line up your statements like that.  It implies you're working with batches all the way through.  manji's answer has more idiomatic spacing, though if you find yourself doing this much it's probably better to make some helper functions like my second answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` extension method needs a lambda expression that returns a boolean, but the inner `o.Issues.Select` returns an IEnumerable of boolean to the outer `Select(o => o` which result in the exception you're getting.

Try using `Any` instead which verifies that at least one element verifies the condition:

```
    items = batch.Select(
               b => b.Items.Where(
                             i => i.ItemOrganisations.Any(
                                     o => o.Issues.Any(x => x.Code == issueNo)
                                  )
                    )
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to select through multiple layers of enumerables. In those cases you need `SelectMany` which flattens out the layers, not `Select`.  LINQ's syntax sugar is made specifically to make `SelectMany` easier to reason about:

```
var items = from item in batch.Items
            from org in item.ItemOrganizations
            from issue in org.Issues
            where issue.Code == issueNo
            select item;
```

The compiler translates that into something like this:

```
var items = batch.Items
    .SelectMany(item => item.ItemOrganizations, (item, org) => new {item, org})
    .SelectMany(@t => @t.org.Issues, (@t, issue) => new {@t, issue})
    .Where(@t => @t.issue.Code == issueNo)
    .Select(@t => @t.@t.item);
```

You can always wrap this in a `Distinct` if you need to avoid duplicate items:

```
var items = (from item in batch.Items
            from org in item.ItemOrganizations
            from issue in org.Issues
            where issue.Code == issueNo
            select item).Distinct();
```

Comment: @xer That said manji's answer will be a bit faster because his `Select` will only return an item once.  Mine will return an item multiple times if there are multiple issues with the corresponding issueNo on that item.  Hence the need for `Distinct` on mine, whereas manji's shouldn't ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do based on your code but I think you're looking for something like this;

```
var issue = batch.Select(b => b.Items).Select(i => i.Issues).Where(x => x.Code == issueNo).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above query will return the first issue where the Issues Code property is equal to issueNo. If no such issue exists it will return null.

One problem (the cause of your first error) in your query is that you're using select like it's a where clause at the end of your query. Select is used to project an argument, when you do `Select(x => x.Code == issueNo)` what you're doing is projecting x.Code to a bool, the value returned by that select is the result of `x.Code == issueNo`, it seems like you want that condition in a where clause and then you want to return the issue which satisfies it which is what my query is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
items =  from b in batch.Include("Items")
         where b.Items.Any(x=>x.Code==issueNo)
         select b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting lost in lambdas.  Your LINQ chains are all embedded in each other, making it harder to reason about.  I'd recommend some helper functions here:

```
static bool HasIssueWithCode(this ItemOrganization org, int issueNo)
{
    return org.Issues.Any(issue => issue.Code == issueNo);
}

static bool HasIssueWithCode(this Item items, int issueNo)
{
    return items.ItemOrganizations.Any(org => org.HasIssueWithCode(issueNo));
}
```

Then your answer is simply and obviously

```
var items = batch.Items.Where(item => item.HasIssueWithCode(issueNo));
```

If you inline these functions, the result is the exact same as manji's (so give manji credit for the correct answer), but I think it's a bit easier to read.